# NVBlas library in Cuda Tools for Mac 5.5

Tags: cuda

I just installed the Cuda Tools (5.5) on a Mac and I cannot locate the NVBlas library. It's not where the docs suggest it should be. Anyone having the same issue or know where it is? Checked all the libs and it's no where to be found.

Comment: NVBLAS is only available in CUDA 6.0.

Comment: @cklin: please add that as an answer so we can get this of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVBLAS is available starting with CUDA 6.0, not CUDA 5.5.

Comment: Just installed CUDA 6.0 and checked the lib directories in /developer/nvidia/cuda-6.0/lib still not there?

Comment: It indeed looks like it is missing.  I have filed a bug report with Nvidia.

Comment: I have confirmed with NVIDIA that this is a problem with their 6.0 release candidate and that it will be fixed in the final release package.  In the meantime, you may want to try their Ubuntu version, which seems to include libnvblas.so.

Comment: Thanks looks like I'll be off Mac for a bit and fire up a Ubuntu VM.